# Retain File Object valuie in a Form after File Upload

Tags: file-upload, playframework

I have a form which has some input fields along with file object. Once the form is submitted, validation would happen in server side. If validation fails I need to show the same page to the user with the values he/she given. Im able to retain all the values except file object.

Is it possible in Playframework?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, maybe with some flash/flex object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could find a suitable way to send the file object back to the browser I do not believe it is possible to set the value of an `<input type="file" />` due to security restrictions.

I would recommend validating the form in the browser first before uploading the data. If you do not want to write a load of validation code yourself then you could use a [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Comment: that's correct. for security reasons, websites are not allowed to set the value of a input type='file'